# Simple Graph with 5 vertices of degrees 2, 3, 3, 3, 5

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm taking a class in Discrete Mathematics, and one of the problems in my homework asks for a Simple Graph with 5 vertices of degrees 2, 3, 3, 3, and 5. How can I have more than 4 edges? I'm really confused, maybe I don't really understand what a "Simple Graph" means.

Comment: What do you think the definition of "simple graph" is?

Comment: Has no loops, no multi-edges.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that they might have intended for you to state that such a graph cannot exist?

Comment: Since there are $5$ vertices, no vertex can have degree more than $4$.

Comment: Looks like professor made a typo then

Comment: @Boshu Maybe, I'm not too sure.

Comment: @AyaanSiddiqui  I would tend to agree with you, but it depends on exactly how the problem was stated.  Was it an existence question?

Comment: @Randall You're right, it actually is. I do have to prove whether it exists or not. Thanks, I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 5 vertices, it is not possible in a simple graph to have a maximum degree of more than $5-1=4$. Hence, such a simple graph as required does not exist.